# Can't get anything from software center (12.04)

Tags: 12.04, package-management, software-installation

Everytime I try to get something from the software center, it fails along with the following:

```
installArchives() failed: 
Extracting templates from packages: 50%
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...

Extracting templates from packages: 50%
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...

Extracting templates from packages: 50%
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...

Extracting templates from packages: 50%
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
Error in function:
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 12.04 does not have all repositories enabled by default. You can open Software Sources or Synaptic, and go to Settings - Repositories - Other Software. Enable/check 'Canonical Partners' and the 'Independent' repos and reload your Software Sources list. You can try using Software Center after that.

Speaking of Software Center, I never use it, I prefer to use Synaptic and the terminal window. This way I know for sure if the software I install will work or not on my system. I do use the search field in Software Center sometimes to learn more about new software but I usually install the software via Synaptic.